# render component using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a component based on the component Id.

```
//react js container
<div> 
{document.getElementById('elementId')}
</div>
```

When I run, it says objects are not a valid child

Comment: my bad, typos removed

Comment: So, what are you trying to achieve here? Right now, you seem to be trying to insert an DOM element object into some JSX. Are you trying to copy that element somehow?

Comment: Yes I want to extract an element from DOM, and want to render in JSX

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a javascript object instead of JSX. The "Objects are not valid as a React child" error happens when trying to render a javascript object instead of using the data from the object to create and return JSX.

Also, you can't store reference to an element using the document.getElementById in react. React provides `useRef` hook for storing references to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` will get you an element. Elements are not components, hence the error.

To use a component, you need to import the function or class and then use JSX: `<ComponentName />`.

---

If you want to move an element to another place in the DOM, inside some content then you need to do so in an effect hook with a reference to the place you want to put it.

**I strongly recommend not doing this** as if you unmount the component then the element will end up being destroyed and if you later remount the component then it won't exist. (You might be able to compensate for that by moving the element elsewhere in the cleanup function you can return the effect hook).

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const div = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        div.current?.appendChild(element);
    }, []);

    return <div ref={div}></div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin. Actually, I'm doing this because I want to render a component in fullscreen view. I have another component that covers up fullscreen. I'm extracting a component that is already mounted & taking this component into the parent container. If the approach is not good, please suggest me

Comment: I didn't think it was possible for something outside of a full screen element to appear about a full screen element. I suggest asking a new question, focusing on [actual problem instead of the perceived solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and include a [mcve].

Comment: got it @Quentin